# What's the problem with my Python project?

Tags: python

This is my school assignment project.
The project is supposed to count the number of diameters of a polygon

```
z=int(input("The number of sides:"))

if z<3:

    print("ERROR")

else:

    w=z*(z-3)//2

    print("Number of diameters:" ,w)
```

The number of polygon diameters was supposed to be displayed, but a few slides were displayed

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>

    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start

    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)

  File "<string>", line 3

        print("ERROR")

    ^

SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0

[Program finished]
```

Comment: The character [U+00A0](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0) is a non-breaking space. It's an invisible character which looks like a space but is not the same. You need to replace any instance of this character with a space.

Comment: Did you copy-paste this from a formatted text editor like Word? Oftentimes those sorts of characters get inserted when you do things like that. You need to use a raw text editor (like Notepad) or a code editor (like Emacs or Pycharm) to write code.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy+pasted OPs code into my PyCharm, the code worked. Only suggestion is to clean up the code with less white space to ensure you are not copy+pasting in fake spaces like one of the commenters suggested:

```
z = int(input("The number of sides:"))

if z < 3:
    print("ERROR")
else:
    w = z*(z-3)//2
    print("Number of diameters:", w)
```

It also looks like an android device is somehow involved (pydroid3), which could be evidence of a faulty copy-paste but that is irrelevant since we don't have that information.

Answer (score -3):

w=z*(z-3)//2

I think in this code have math problem.
Because if z is number 3 we get 0 // 2 = 0 answer

for what it will be Error

Comment: The OP's code isn't even being executed. (I suspect it is producing the wrong output, but this isn't related to the reported problem.)